# Given $u_{n+1}=u_n+\frac{1}{n^\alpha u_n}$. Show that $u_n\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^\alpha u_1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

Let $u_{n+1}=u_n+\dfrac{1}{n^\alpha u_n}$ for all $n\geqslant1$ and $u_1>0$.

Show that for all $n\geqslant 1$:
$$\displaystyle u_n\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^\alpha u_1}.$$

I found that :

$$u_{n+1}-u_1\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^\alpha u_1},$$

but not the desired result.

Comment: Why is it even true for $n=1$? This would require  $u_1 \leq \frac{1}{u_1}$, i.e. $u_1 \in (0,1]$.

Comment: I don't know. Do you think something is missing? [I think too].

Comment: Well, the statement is already false for $n=1$, if you choose $u_1=2$. Where is the question from?